# Create text corresponding to multiple variable assignments from a single variable

Tags: shell, text-processing, variable

I have a variable that has a value like this

```
line=dog,/path1,/path2
```

What I want is to create a variable from the value; i.e `dog` should be the variable and want to get the below output:

```
dog=/path1,/path2
dog1=/path1
dog2=/path2
```

Similarly if I have `line=bull,/val1,/val2` I need the below output

```
bull=/val1,/val2
bull1=/val1
bull2=/val2
```

Note that `line` will have only three values separated by commas.

Comment: I thought I understood from the title that you want new variables to be set; do you want variables, or do you want text output instead?

Comment: I need the output exactly how I mentioned. If I get them in another file, that would great. When I cat the file I should get this
`bull=/val1,/val2`
`bull1=/val1`
`bull2=/val2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's the thing you're trying to do:

```
line='dog,/path1,/path2'
IFS=', ' read -r -a dog <<< "$line"

echo "$dog"
dog
echo "${dog[1]}"
/path1
echo "${dog[2]}"
/path2
```

This assumes that your shell is bash.

Comment: No. I have clearly described my question. I don't have any like you mentioned.

Comment: Hi friend. It is better now ?

Comment: didn't you want `dog=/path1,/path2` ?

Comment: Or echo ${dog[@]} to display all values! Like Jeff says .... and you can put ',' if you want using sed or for loops....

Answer (score 2):

Here's a bash-centric solution:

```
IFS=, read -r -a vars <<<"$line"
printf "%s\n" "${vars[0]}=${vars[1]},${vars[2]}" "${vars[0]}1=${vars[1]}" "${vars[0]}2=${vars[2]}"
```

The first line splits your `$line` variable into pieces based on the commas. The second line, working from the inside-out:

1. outputs the first value (e.g. 'dog'), equals-sign, then the second two values,
2. outputs the first value suffixed by `1`, equals-sign, then the second value,
3. outputs the first value, suffixed by `2`, equals-sign, then the third value,
4. `printf` those three strings, separated by newlines.

This answer is, as your question is, hard-coded to having three values in `$line`.

Sample input & output (the leading `$` are the shell prompts):

```
$ line=dog,/path1,/path2
$ IFS=, read -r -a vars <<<"$line"
$ printf "%s\n" "${vars[0]}=${vars[1]},${vars[2]}" "${vars[0]}1=${vars[1]}" "${vars[0]}2=${vars[2]}"
dog=/path1,/path2
dog1=/path1
dog2=/path2
```

You can redirect the printf output to a file easily enough.

Comment: I am putting +1 for you because your answer is based identical as the question, i thinked the user dont really want that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash`, you can do something like this (with extra `echo` statements to show what's happening at each stage):

```sh
$ line=dog,/path1,/path2

$ newline=$(printf "%s\n" "$line" | 
            perl -n -e 'BEGIN {$count=1};
                        my ($var,@values) = split /,/;
                        print "$var=" . join(",",@values);
                        foreach (@values) {
                            printf "%s%i=\"%s\" ",$var, $count++, $_
                        }')

$ echo "$newline"
dog=/path1,/path2 dog1=/path1 dog2=/path2

$ declare $newline

$ declare | grep '^dog'
dog=/path1,/path2
dog1=/path1
dog2=/path2
```

This uses `perl` to split `$line` by commas.  The first field is saved in `$var`, the remainder in an array called `@values`.  Then it produces output suitable for use with the bash `declare` command to set variables.

Note that `$newline` is not and should not be double-quoted on the `declare` line.  If it is double-quoted, `declare` will only get one argument rather than three separated by spaces.

One unpleasant side-effect of the lack of quoting here is that the `declare` **WILL** fail if any of the field values contain space characters etc.  e.g. `line=dog,/path /with / spaces,/path2`.  You can fix this if required by outputting appropriate quoting from the `print` and `printf` statements in the `perl` script.  And/or by defining `$newline` as a bash array instead of a string.  Left as an exercise for the reader, as I've already shown enough of the principle/technique being used here.

If you want them declared as exported variables, use:

```
declare -x $newline
```

see `help declare` for more details.

BTW, in `ksh`, you can use `typeset` instead of `declare`.   `typeset` is also supported by `bash` but considered obsolete (see `help typeset` in `bash`).

---

Finally: are you sure you wouldn't prefer to use a shell array variable (e.g. `dog[0]=/path1,/path2`, `dog[1]=/path1`, and `dog[2]=/path2`) rather than separate variables?
This is the kind of thing that they exist for.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.  I define the line as you have.  Next, I parse our the first comma-separated token from the line (I assume here that will be valid for a variable name).  Then I construct two new variables based on the first token, and assign them to the second and third comma-separated tokens from the line.

```
line="dog,/path1,/path2"
first="$(echo "${line}" | awk -F, '{ print $1 }')"
eval "${first}1=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F, '{ print $2 }')"
eval "${first}2=$(echo "${line}" | awk -F, '{ print $3 }')"

echo "${dog1}"
/path1
echo "${dog2}"
/path2
```